# Proper way to call the instance attribute of the parent class using super in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following codes, trying to get a better understanding how `super` work in python

```
class Person:
  species = "human"

  def __init__(self, name, age):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age

  def sing(self, song):
    return "{} wants to sing the {} song".format(self.name, song)

class Student(Person):
  def __init__(self, name, age, mark):
    self.mark = mark
    super(Student, self).__init__(name, age, mark)

student = Student(24, 8, "Ema")
```

this code crash with the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 23, in <module>
    student = Student(24, 8, "Ema")
  File "main.py", line 17, in __init__
    super(Student, self).__init__(name, age, mark)
TypeError: __init__() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

I am trying to create an object the Student with the instance attributes of the parent class, what am I doing wrong exactly?

Comment: ``Person`` doesn't take a ``mark`` argument, so ``super(Student, self).__init__(name, age)`` is correct. Note that you don't need arguments to ``super`` itself in most cases: ``super().__init__(name, age)`` should be fine.

Answer (score -1):

a good solution as an example:

```
class Person:
  species = "human"

  def __init__(self, name, age):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age

  def sing(self, song):
    return "{} will sing: {}".format(self.name, song)


class Profession(Person):
  def __init__(self, title, company, name, age):    # HERE
    super().__init__(name, age)                     # HERE
    self.title = title
    self.company = company


person = Person("James", 12)

print(person.__class__.species)

print(person.name)

print(person.sing("Tomorrow never die"))

profession = Profession("President", "Rathor Inc.", "Ema", 43)

print(profession.name)
```